# In Geonodes, combining any 2 arbitrary closed curve to form a filled mesh between the two curves

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to combine two closed curves, (for example, two circles, to form a flat doughnut-like shape, or two different shapes like a square with a circle inside.)

I've tried to play around with geonodes but I can't find a way to do this. I tried to play with "Curve To Mesh" and "Extrude Mesh" but none of it worked for me. It was easy outside of geonodes using knife project, but I wanted to find out how it would be done with geonodes.

[image: example]

Oh, one more thing, I'm trying to avoid using mesh boolean difference because of performance issues.

Any tip or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'm very new to geonodes, just started out when 3.0 was released. I love the geonode concept so I really love to learn a lot about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you mean like this?

[image]

Just join two basic curves and use fill curve.

[image]

or a "donut" like thing:

[image]

Comment: aw fudge, that was embarrassing. I was wondering why yours worked and mine didn't until I realised I was using Mesh Circle instead of  Curve Circle.  Thanks again, Chris. This is so embarrassing.

Comment: no problem. I am fighting with geonodes so often.... ;) and watching tons of tutorials  and wondering what is already possible with it ;)

Comment: Mind if I ask a follow up since you mentioned the Extrude? Or should I post it as a separate question? Whenever I extrude, the bottom part is open, I usually just add another extrude and join the two, but when I inspect the normals, the one at the bottom becomes reversed normal. Any tips on that?

Comment: oh, there's a flip face node that i could use with the second extrude, but is that the right thing to do?

Comment: pls open a new question so everybody else who has the same question as you can read it too and learn from it too ;)

Comment: but yes, that's right to do, i read another question. Extrude will not close face at the bottom.

Comment: sure thing, thanks again Chris :) you've taught me a lot :D

Comment: thank you and glad i could help!